# How to index an array with its indices in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

For example, I have an array and its indices:

```
  xx = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
  index = np.argwhere(xx>3)
```

If I use

```
 xx[index]
```

I get an error:

```
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

But if I write:

```
xx[index[0], index[1]]
```

I get:

```
array([4, 5])
```

Which is exactly what I want. But if I have an N dimensional array, do I need to write

```
xx[index[0], index[1], ..., index[N]]
```

in this case, or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Why did you *use* argwhere? Why not just `xx[xx>3]`?

Comment: It is just an example. In my case, I do have indices array like `index` in the example.

Comment: `xx[tuple(index)]` works for me.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: It might look like it works, but only by fluke, since `index` happens to be its own transpose. If you try it with `index = np.argwhere(xx>2)`, you get an IndexError.

Comment: @f.c. did the answer work for you?

Comment: @jojo You gave me good hint. But in my case, I need to manipulate the coordinates `index`, say calculate the mean of the coordinates, and I need convert tuple to array to be able to make the calculation, then convert array back to tuple to be able to do the indexing.

Comment: @f.c.I see. But the challenges when modifying the indices are not really present in your question then, right?! Anyways, glad I could give you some hints.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the documentation of numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html):

> The **output of argwhere is not suitable for indexing** arrays.
> For this purpose **use nonzero(a) instead**.

So, this would be the recommended way and it works just fine:

```py
>>> xx = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
>>> index = np.nonzero(xx>3)
>>> xx[index]
array([4, 5])
```

---

The point of `np.argwhere` is essentially that it will group the indices by element and so the resulting output will be of the shape `(M, xx.ndim)` where M is the number of non-zero elements, which makes it clearly not suitable for indexing.

`np.nonzero`, on the other hand, groups indexes by dimension, returning for each dimension a tuple which is what you need!

So, basically if the elements at *[x1,y1], [x2,y2]* and *[x3, y3]* meet your condition, `argwhere` will return an array like this:

```py
[[x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3]]
```

while `nonzero` will return a tuple:

```py
([x1, x2, x3], [y1, y2, y3])
```

Note that the latter is what you need for indexing. Also, the latter is also almost the transpose of the former, so if you are stuck for some reason with an array of the form produced by `argwhere` you can transpose and convert it to a tuple and you are golden. *So `tuple(np.transpose(index))` in your case.* If you are using `argwhere` to get your indices then I'd recommend to simply use `nonzero` instead.

Comment: `argwhere` just returns `np.transpose(np.nonzero(...))`, turning the tuple of `n` arrays into a `n` column array.

Comment: @hpaulj yes exactly! This is what I meant to say with `argwhere` groups by element, where `nonzero` groups by dimension. It is also why you can directly use the output of `nonzero` for indexing, but need to transpose the output of `argwhere` first (or simply use `nonzero` in the first place).

Comment: `np.transpose(index)` isn't enough - you still have to convert back to a tuple (`tuple(index.T)`), since a 2D array is not equivalent to a tuple of 1D arrays for indexing purposes.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica aah geh! thanks for pointing this out, I forgot to check the return type.